# Parse error while converting edi to java?

Tags: java, xml, exception, edi, smooks

I am trying to convert EDI data format to java.

The EDI data is as follows

```
HDR*1*0*59.97*64.92*4.95*Wed Nov 15 13:45:28 EST 2006
CUS*user1*Harry^Fletcher*SD
ORD*1*1*364*The 40-Year-Old Virgin*29.98
ORD*2*1*299*Pulp Fiction*29.99
```

I have referred to the folllowing [link](https://github.com/smooks/smooks-examples/tree/master/edi-to-java) while implementing this.

While executing the project, getting the below error:

```
Caused by: org.smooks.api.SmooksException: Parse Error: Failed to populate order-item[2]. Cause: Parse Error: Terminator '%NL;' not found
```

I tired executing the mentioned project, wanted data formatted to be java object.
But ended up with the below error

```
Caused by: org.smooks.api.SmooksException: Parse Error: Failed to populate order-item[2]. Cause: Parse Error: Terminator '%NL;' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a newline at the end of the EDI document hence the error. For some reason, the newline isn't rendered when [viewing the example file from GitHub](https://github.com/smooks/smooks-examples/blob/master/edi-to-java/input-message.edi#L4) but it's present when you view it locally.